# Prime vs Maximal Ideals of Modules over Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be an $R[X]$ algebra and finitely generated as an $R[X]$-module, where $R$ is a field (so $R[X]$ is a PID). Is it generically true that nonzero prime ideals in $M$ are maximal? If not, what additional conditions are necessary (on either $M$ or $R$)?

Comment: What do you mean by an ideal of a module? Perhaps you are supposing that $M$ is an algebra instead? Perhaps you mean an associated prime?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey $M$ is an algebra - edited.

Comment: Do you really want $R[X]$ to be a PID or just $R$? Because if $R[X]$ is a PID then this is just a weird way to say that $R$ is a field...

Comment: @GreginGre I want $R[X]$ to be a PID - saying $R$ is a field does seem a better wording, so edited.

Comment: Note that if $M$ is itself a domain, then the answer is yes (otherwise no as in @RobertRosen ‘s answer). This is because $M$ (being in particular an integral extension of $R[X]$) will have the same Krull dimension (one) as $R[X]$, and in a domain, the only height 0 prime is the 0 ideal. So every non-0 prime is has height 1 and is therefore  maximal.

Comment: @AviSteiner Thank you for the example. Is there a way to see this without appealing to the Krull dimension?

Comment: @RobertRosen Not that i know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M=R[X]^2$, and $I=R[X]\times\{0\}$. Then $M$ is a finitely generated $R[X]$-module, and an $R[X]$-algebra. Since $M/I\simeq R[X]$ is a domain (since $R$ is a field), $I$ is a non zero prime ideal, which is not maximal, since $R[X]$ is not a field.

Note that the argument works if we replace $R$ by any domain, so there is no real hope to get a positive result by strengthening assumptions on $R$.

Anyway, what you really want is $M$ to have Krull dimension $\leq 1$. Since $R[X]$ has dimension $1$ already, what you wish for is probably equivalent to ask $M$ to be integral over $R[X]$ (meaning any element of $M$ is the zero of some monic polynomial with coefficients in $R[X]$).

Comment: By $K[X]$, do you refer to the algebraic closure of $R[X]$?

Comment: sorry, $K$ is $R$